# Get the first to the last element of each group in the form of a datatable using only data.table operations

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following datatable:

```
datatable_example <- data.table(a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4), b = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'))  

 > datatable_example
    a b
 1: 1 A
 2: 1 B
 3: 1 B
 4: 1 A
 5: 2 B
 6: 2 B
 7: 2 A
 8: 3 A
 9: 3 B
10: 3 A
11: 3 A
12: 4 A
13: 4 A
```

I would like to filter this datatable in a way that, for each column "a" it keeps all column "b" elements until the last letter "B". So the desired output is:

```
> output
    a b
 1: 1 A
 2: 1 B
 3: 1 B
 4: 2 B
 5: 2 B
 6: 3 A
 7: 3 B
```

Do you know anyway I can do this using data.table? I would not like to separate in 3 other datatables (using something like lapply) and then rbind or rbindlist them.

Comment: what happens if there are no B for a particular a?

Comment: You are right, just noticed this problem in my code... Both answers don't deal with this problem but in your case it is possible to eliminate NA cases after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select rows until last `"B"` value in each group.

```
library(data.table)
datatable_example[, .SD[seq_len(max(which(b == 'B')))], a]

#   a b
#1: 1 A
#2: 1 B
#3: 1 B
#4: 2 B
#5: 2 B
#6: 3 A
#7: 3 B
```

Comment: Aren't you assuming there will be only one "A" at the end of each group? There could be more of them. I edited the question so it will be more clear.

Comment: I misunderstood the question earlier. Updated the answer now .

Comment: Thank you. Will take yours as the answer as it seems more simple (readable).

Comment: I had chosen ur answer but it doesn't handle the exceptional case where there's no "B" for a specific group. Any ideas to handle it with your simple code?

Comment: You can add an `if` condition : `datatable_example[, if(any(b == 'B')) .SD[seq_len(max(which(b == 'B')))], a]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option:

```
DT[, rn := .I][
    DT[CJ(a, b="B", unique=TRUE), on=.(a, b), mult="last"],
    on=.(a, rn<=rn)]
```

output:

```
   a b rn i.b
1: 1 A  3   B
2: 1 B  3   B
3: 1 B  3   B
4: 2 B  6   B
5: 2 B  6   B
6: 3 A  9   B
7: 3 B  9   B
```

data:

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
    b = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'))
```

Comment: would you mind explaining what the mult argument does?

Comment: @daniellga `mult="last"` picks the last row when there are multiple matches. it is an argument for `[.data.table` (see the `mult` argument in `?data.table`)